# IIS Header too long

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

I use a lot of claims and store them in token. I encountered this error before only in swagger, and clearing cache always worked for me. However, now I see this error in production environment. Current "Authorization" header that is giving this error is ~16kb. I tried to increase "Authorization" header size in IIS, added these to web.config

```
<system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="500000000"  executionTimeout="120" />
    </system.web>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
<security>
          <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="500000000" />
          </requestFiltering>
        </security>
```

and added tried increasing limit in Kestrel:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .ConfigureKestrel((context, options) =>
            {
                options.Limits.MaxRequestHeadersTotalSize = 1048576;
            });
    }
```

None of the above helped. I didn't find other solutions, what else can be done here?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/820129/http-sys-registry-settings-for-windows Incoming HTTP requests are checked by http.sys, and there is a size limit for headers.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to make it more than 64kb? If you post this as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @LexLi  , give me a chance, let me try. (^.^)

Comment: If @LexLi is fine with that, I'll accept your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Lex Li](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11182/lex-li) said.
According to the MSDN,
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/820129/http-sys-registry-settings-for-windows
We could try to set up the `MaxRequestBytes` property in the below Registration location.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters
```

If the property doesn’t exist, create and set up it.

> The registry takes high priority as the driver is the entry point of
> packets. It is also a server-wide setting for all incoming HTTP
> packets.

Please refer to the below thread.
[Do web.config header size limits override http.sys limits in the registry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35749180/do-web-config-header-size-limits-override-http-sys-limits-in-the-registry)
https://serverfault.com/questions/417113/iis-6-header-too-big-how-to-tune-this-iis-setting
[How to increase size limit for HTTP header value in request for Azure IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42862828/how-to-increase-size-limit-for-http-header-value-in-request-for-azure-iis?rq=1)

Comment: It works, but there is still a limit for 64kb. Is there a way to allow headers larger than 64kb?